# Screen Resolution in AVD-Manager

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I've started working with Android Apps and wanted to create my first "Hello World". With the default settings from Xamarin the resolution of the device is very low and it is not like a real phone.

[image]

For instance the startup "android" is chopped of. Are there some params where I could change the sreenresolution and so?

FIY: Setting LCD pixel height and width in the hardwaresettings doesn't help; thats what I've tried.

Thank you!